# Sabre web service unsupported command

Tags: web-services, api, soap, sabre

I am trying to move a traveler profile into a PNR by sending the "NM" Sabre command via the SabreCommandLLSRQ web service call and get "Invalid Input for GDS" as the response. This command works via Sabre Red, but for some reason doesn't seem support via webservice.

Is there a list of unsupported commands, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Output format of the request was set to "SDS" instead of "SCREEN" and that apparently has some serious side effects on what commands can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Legacy Stars or new Sabre Profiles?

Have you checked out the Move Profile to PNR service API?

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/profiles/build_reservation/Copy_Profile_to_Itinerary

Comment: This is for legacy profiles. I believe the answer to the problem is that you should use `SCREEN` as the Output parameter value instead of `SDS`. Apparently `SDS` Output option has a side effect that only a subset of commands are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be relevant, but if you're using PassengerDetailsRQ you can just set UniqueId on ProfileRQ

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Passenger_Details

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote    I like to connect Flights api App using php file dsbridge.php by making
>   ajax request to the class curl Bridge getting array response
>   error - invalid_client
>       error_descr - Credentials are missing or the syntax is not correct.
>       When I make the _dsAppKey using base64 tool using this procedure.

```
 1. Base64 your Client Id            
 2. Base64 Client Secret            
 3. Concatenate both Base64 values with a :            
 4. Base64 the concatenation.  

It still gives me the Response code as NULL. This code gives me the 
Access token. You have to send another request to the Sabre Api.  

Pl. help me with the complete example.
```